# Is there a way I can get AI to generate Chinese reading materials, and track the number of characters I've read?

Tags: llm, recommendation, chinese

For language learners, LLMs can be a great way to practice reading.  Recently, I've been getting ChatGPT to write articles at an appropriate level, and copy/paste them into a website called LanguageCrush because it can track how many words I've read.  However, I'm not a fan of such bookkeeping tasks, so I'm wondering if there's dedicated software for this task.

**Question**: Is there a way I can get AI to generate Chinese reading materials, and track the number of characters I've read?

Comment: About the count: Do you want to get the number of characters, or the number of *different* characters?

Comment: Number of (not necessarily unique) characters.  I.e., it should tell me how much I've read.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can get AI to generate Chinese reading materials

E.g. [prompt `Write a story in Mandarin`](https://chat.openai.com/share/b9e7af68-70f8-4c48-a1f3-ec52160604ed):

[image]

> and track the number of characters I've read

Use a basic character counter, e.g. in Google Document.